# Can lambda be used instead of void operator?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm wondering about this c++11 example and using `operator` for `algorithm` functions
(`for_each`, `remove_if` etc.).
For example, I have 2 blocks:

```
struct UpdateFunc
{
    void operator () (int i) const
    {
        // blablabla
    }
};
```

and

```
constexpr auto UpdateFunc = [](int i) -> void
{
    // blablabla
};
```

Using this for `operator`:

`UpdateFunc f; for_each(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), f);`

Using this for `lambda` :

`std::for_each(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), UpdateFunc);`

Are these functions the same?

Comment: That's exactly what lambdas are, syntactic sugar for functors. Their value however is typically in being written *inline*. `std::for_each(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), [](int) { /*w/e*/ });`

Comment: When you look at https://godbolt.org/z/h68MbT33d you see that the compiler generates the same instructions for the functor and the lambda. So yes.

Comment: The `-> void` for the lambda will be inferred.  In my experience, putting the return type for the lambda is only necessary for situations where you want conversion or covariance, like `[]() -> unique_ptr<Base> { return make_unique<Derived>(1, 2, 3); }`

Comment: You seem to have noticed the big difference: the former is a type and the latter a value, but that bears highlighting